# How to store time in HH:mm format in mongo db

Tags: mongodb, timestamp, nosql

I have a requirement where I want to store "startWindow" and "endWindow" property in mongodb document, Is there any way we can keep the window in HH:mm time format. Below is the expected format of document:

```
{
   windowStart: "07:00",
   windowEnd: "16:00"
}
```

Comment: You should always use `Date` objects to store date/time value, **never** use strings. Anyway, what is your question? You already wrote down what you like to do.

Comment: you should insert as Date object after when you want to get you could get as `HH:mm`

Comment: why not strings? or even as number. for example , 7:00 am can stored as minutes elapsed from 12:00 ie 420. You need to specify your requirement. For example, do you need to do math operations on them? Or just show on label?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.